# Elasticsearch create index from binary database content

Tags: database, indexing, binary, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch and want to index binary content from a database (for instance pdf files). Do I need a special plugin? I can connect to the database via _river jdbc and indexed "normal" text-based content like contacts.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/MY_RIVER/_meta' -d '{
     "type" : "jdbc",
     "jdbc" : {
     "index" : "MY_BINARY_INDEX",
          "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
          "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_directory",
          "user" : "My_User",
          "password" : "My_Password",
          "sql" : "select * from MY_TABLE"
     }
}
```

thanks & best regards

pit

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html

Comment: the binary content is part of a table in a database not single files. I need to index this content (name_of_file , binary content)

Comment: Attachment type indexes content of the file.

Comment: I know, but i have to index binary content from a database, there are no files in a filesystem, how can I create that kind of index?

Comment: do you want to search the binary content? or just store it in Elasticsearch and search on other fields?